# GoogleMap addPolygon throws exception about empty list

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Have a rediculous exception:

```
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.b: List<LatLng> cannot be empty.
```

Where the list is not empty obviously:

```
List<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new LatLng(0, 0));
list.add(new LatLng(10, 10));
list.add(new LatLng(10, 0));
list.add(new LatLng(0, 0));

map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions().fillColor(Color.RED).addHole(list));
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a hole to an empty polygon (you are using `addHole`). You need to add the coordinate list to the `PolygonOptions` using `addAll`:

```
map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions().fillColor(Color.RED).addAll(list));
```